# jupiter notebook memory cannot be released

Tags: ipython

I am doing a simple experiment and realized the memory just cannot be released whatever i do in jupiter notebook.

Here's the experiment, firstly create a np.array roughly about 800MB,

```
var_tmp = np.random.randn(10000,10000)
```

I monitor memory usage in linux with `top`. After this command, indeed a 800MB more usage has been added to python.

Now I am trying to release the memory,

```
%reset_selective -f var_tmp
```

I check memory using top, now nothings changes...

By repeating the process above, the memory just keeps accumulating and going up and up and up. This is really annoying... Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

For my setup

- Ubuntu LTS 16.04
- Python 3.6.4
- IPython 6.2.1

a simple

```
del var_temp
```

releases the memory.

Comment: Just checked with my python 2 environment and `del var_temp` also works there. My versions in the python 2 env are: python - 2.7.14, jupyter - 1.0.0, jupyter_client 5.1.0, jupyter_console 5.2.0, jupyter_core 4.3.0.

Comment: Are you also on Linux?